# Trouble reading data from JSON file and displaying it on Canvas

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, html5-canvas

**Background**

(New to JS and 1st time using canvas)

I am trying to read a JSON file from https://analytics.usa.gov/ and display it using a canvas. I want just the first 8 records to be populated in a drop down.

I was successful in getting a dump of the file locally on my machine. Code is here (https://jsfiddle.net/uh8jamdo/)

What I was trying to do is :
1) Page Title from the data should be populated in Drop Down 
2) When the User selects one and clicks submit. I want to display the Page Title, URL and active users of that particular Page Title.

Below is my attempt. Can some one please guide me. I have written code to display canvas, text and update the data.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var button = document.getElementById("previewButton");
  button.onclick = previewHandler;


}

function previewHandler() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("analytics");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  drawText(canvas, context);

}

// draws all the text, including the Analytics
function drawText(canvas, context) {

  context.font = "50px serif";
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.font = "bold 1em sans-serif";
  context.textAlign = "left";
  context.fillText("No of People online on Govt Websites", 20, 40);


  // draw the analytics!
  selectObj = document.getElementById("site");
  index = selectObj.selectedIndex;
  var site = selectObj[index].value;
  context.font = "italic 1.2em serif";
  context.fillText(site, 30, 100);



}





function updateAnalytics(site) {
  var siteSelection = document.getElementById("site");

  // add all data to the site dropdown
  for (var i = 0; i < site.length; i++) {
    site = site[i];

    // create option
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = site.text;

    // strip any quotes out of the site so they don't mess up our option
    option.value = site.text.replace("\"", "'");

    // add option to select
    siteSelection.options.add(option);
  }
  // make sure the top tweet is selected
  siteSelection.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="200" id="analytics">
  <p>You need canvas to see the Analytics Data</p>
  <p>This example requires a browser that supports the HTML5 Canvas feature.</p>
</canvas>

<p>
  <label for="site">Pick a Site</label>
  <select id="site"></select>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" id="previewButton" value="Preview">
</p>
</form>
</br>
<script src="https://analytics.usa.gov/data/live/top-pages-realtime.json">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have it, but there are enough strange things that I figure I can modify your code and you can study what I've done.  A few issues I spotted:

- Instead of hardcoding a script into the html document, we can fetch the contents of URL's through `XMLHttpRequest`.  You are going to run into some timing issues.
- There is no real need to use `form` and `submit` these days.  Modern web design will usually maintain a stateful object on the client, and will communicate with various back ends using things like `XMLHttpRequest`, above.   By doing this, we don't have to redraw the page every time we get a response back from the server.  When the user clicks submit, you can catch that event, but there is a protocol you need to follow (return false from the handler) to prevent the page from reloading and blowing away the user's selection.  The user will not get to see your canvas, because you'll be reloading a fresh canvas every time.  They also will not see their selection because you'll be resetting it after every submit.
- We don't need to strip quotes when setting the javascript value.  First, because these things will usually get escaped for you, but second, because it's actually easier in your case to just store the index of the selection.  You really don't need value at all.  It may cause issues if you use this modified value as a key.
- Minimize the number of global variables.  Javascript has really good support for [closure](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp), which is a powerful programming construct that allows us to limit the visibility of variables, among other things.  This will make it a lot easier to test your code in the debugger because everything will be grouped in one place.  (More of a style than an actual issue).
- Make sure to clear out your canvas if you plan to reuse it.  Successive calls to `fillText` will clobber the previous text.
- There are plenty of other things we could explore, but hopefully this will get you started.

Also, it's great that you are doing all of this without resorting to external libraries, but you should also check them out -- javascript can do some pretty exciting things.  I recommend [D3.js](http://d3js.org/)

Finally, here is the revised javascript, which I believe does the things you've specified, and which takes into account the advice I've given:

(you can play with the jsfiddle, here:
https://jsfiddle.net/dancingplatypus/L92fq305/6/)

```
var site_analytics = {
    run: function () {
        var ANALYTICS_SITE = 'https://analytics.usa.gov/data/live/top-pages-realtime.json';
        var elem_select = document.getElementById("site");
        var elem_title = document.getElementById("site_title");
        var elem_preview = document.getElementById("previewButton");
        var site_data = null;

        elem_preview.onclick = render_selection;
        elem_select.onchange = render_selection;

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log('heya');
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                site_data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                sync_selector();
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", ANALYTICS_SITE, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        function sync_selector() {
            console.log('boyo');
            elem_select.innerHtml = null;
            if (site_data) {
                for (var loop = 0; loop < Math.min(8, site_data.data.length); loop++) {
                    var item = site_data.data[loop];
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.text = item.page_title;
                    option.value = loop;
                    elem_select.add(option);
                }
            }
            selected_index = (site_data.data.length > 0) ? 0 : null;
            render_selection();
        }

        function render_selection() {
            var index = elem_select.selectedIndex;
            var item = site_data ? site_data.data[index] : null;

            elem_title.innerText = item ? item.page_title : 'n/a';
            var canvas = document.getElementById("analytics");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            drawText(item, canvas, context);
        };

        // draws all the text, including the Analytics
        function drawText(item, canvas, context) {
            context.font = "50px serif";
            context.fillStyle = "black";
            context.font = "bold 1em sans-serif";
            context.textAlign = "left";
            context.fillText("No of People online on Govt Websites", 20, 40);

            // draw the analytics!
            context.font = "italic 1.2em serif";
            context.fillText(item ? item.active_visitors : '', 30, 100);
        }
    }
};

window.onload = function () {
    site_analytics.run();
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael !!

This will surely get me started. There is a lot of things I need to learn from your code. (syntax, about objects etc) 

Shall get  back to you slowly since I have never seen certain code lines before like:
var item = site_data ? site_data.data[index] : null;

many thanks for sharing all the detail explanation and tips to bring people like me up to date.

Comment: You are very welcome.  Just to help you on your way -- the var item = a ? b : c is called a "ternary expression."  The 'site_data' on the left is evaluated for "truthiness."  (see: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/ )

Javascript has some strange behavior, and a lot of it has to do with its unique evolution.  But stick with it.  One day, when you are programming in a more classical language, you'll think to yourself, "why can't they make this easy, like it is in javascript?"  :-D

Comment: thanks for the update. As a UX designer I am usually obsessed with user experience and lately I got curious about Javascript, Jquery etc. I feel it brings to the table great features that can enrich user experience. (or  hide complexity).                                                                                 I do not know if I will ever get to classical languages frankly :)